# Add JDBC jars dynamically in RCP project

Tags: jdbc, jar, eclipse-rcp

I have to build a RCP application which connects to database and according to the query have to display the values.
But I cannot embed the jars into the package. So please help me to add those jars dynamically into the tool.

Comment: Eclipse. I dont want to add those jar files in class path using eclipse.Need to add the jars using code.Because as database changes jar required also changes

Comment: please help i am stuck at this part.